# How to use keystores for multi Store

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, huawei-developers, appgallery

I have an android app that's intended for both google play and app gallery , it's one project with 2 **flavours** , for the google play i generated a **keystore** , my questions are that

1- Should I use the google play **keystore** for app gallery or it needs to be a new one ?

2- **Bundle id** for appgallery can be same as google play or not ? Any pros and cons for same/different id ?

3- Does app gallery accepts aab or only apk as for google there is no choice (only aab)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally use the same key-store and the same package name.
With `versionNameSuffix` the resulting packages will by easier to identify.

If you want to publish AAB to AppGallery Connect, you need to enable signing.
It's the same as on Google Play; the release key will then become an upload key.

The important part is: One can only use the same key-store, while uploading AAB and let Google or Huawei sign the published package. Alike this each channel will use the same upload key - but will nevertheless have their own release key. Else you'll run into trouble, when both stores are installed.

My plugin would also support AAB upload: [`agconnect-publishing-gradle-plugin`](https://github.com/syslogic/agconnect-publishing-gradle-plugin).
So far it's probably only me, who uses it... which means it could use some testing.

Comment: Can you help her please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74169669/add-payment-for-android-app-with-2-flavours

Comment: Hi Martin thanks for help , but your design says that i only need to change versionname , which means my version name on google be 2.0.0Google and same for Huawei 2.0.0Huawei is this an acceptable format to the world ? also my current design says different package name for the stores and also different keyStore ,so is there a problem with my design , is it the best ? or according to your experience there is a better approach ?

Comment: please your feedback Will this cause cross store updates ? meaning uploading on one store updates the version of the other store when both stores are installed ?

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Should I use the google play keystore for app gallery or it needs to be a new one ?

**No you should not, because it will cause cross-platform updates (it may update app gallery version from Google Play).**

> 2- Bundle id for appgallery can be same as google play or not ? Any pros and cons for same/different id ?

**It can be the same:**

**pros:**

**1. Easier for development**

**2. can use same accounts if you are using some 3rd party APIs**

**cons:**

**1- app gallery will try to update the app that you have instaled from Google Play and vise versa (but you can over come this with different keystores)**

> 3- Does app gallery accepts aab or only apk as for google there is no choice (only aab)?

**Yes it accepts AAB**

Comment: Hi  jabbar thanks for the response , So isn't it better to make them with different  bundle  ids to completely get around this specially huawei may block gms in near future ? regarding keystore should i also upload the private key to google in signing as it tells me it's recommended to leave google singing automatic by them ?

Comment: This is only correct while using the same signature, please see my updated answer. And please refrain from excessing formatting, because this doesn't really improve the overall readability.