# Add payment for android app with 2 flavours

Tags: android, google-play, appgallery

I have an android app that's intended for both google play and app gallery , It's one project with 2 flavours , currently i have no user system in my app and i have IAP to enable premium features

Note:

*For the google version of the app i don't let app proceeds until gms exists*

*For the huawei version of the app i don't let app proceeds until hms exists*

**I have these questions :-**

1- If a user with a huawei device paid my app from google play store ,then gms blocked in huawei , does it mean this user will loss his payment ?

2- Is it a usual practise that apps has IAP with no user system and depend only on restore history given by google/huawei accounts store ?

3- To  escape from liablity isn't it  better to make the app in huawei with different bundle id than the one in google ?

4- Any other way to block installment for gms version of the app in huawei ? meaning make google play version for gms devices only and app gallery version for huawei devices only without overlapped installment as for now there are some huawei devices that features both stores?

Comment: One question per question please.

Answer (score 2):

Purchases can be restored, when logging in with the correct currently installed product flavor.

The only problem I see may be devices with both stores installed, which means:

- manual uninstall may be required, when the user is locked out.
- in order to reinstall the proper package with the proper signature.

For reference: I've already explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74160223/549372).

Comment: Hi Martin thanks for help , but your design says that i only need to change versionname , which means my version name on google be `2.0.0Google` and same for Huawei `2.0.0Huawei` is this an acceptable format to the world ?  also my current design says different package name for the stores and also different keyStore ,so is there a problem with my design , is it the best ? or according to your experience there is a better approach ?